# opening a new form dialog on a seperate thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have an object running it's own thread, processing input from a webcam and updating a window Control. During it's operation a user may indicate they wish to calibrate the application where I would essentially like to have the current thread suspend, open a new Form in its own thread, have the user perform their inut and click OK whereupon this temp thread dies and the original resumes. My calibration Form looks like

```
    //Constructor() {}

    public void StartCalibration() {
        Debug.WriteLine("StartCalibration CALLED!");
        var thread = new Thread(Run);
        thread.Start();
    }


    private void Run() {
        while (!finished) {
            //process user input
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        if (image != null)
            g.DrawImage(image, new Point(15, 15));
    }
```

In the original objects thread I have the following

```
    public void Run() {
        if (calibrate == true) {
            CalibrationForm calibrationForm = new CalibrationForm(source);
            if (calibrationForm.InvokeRequired)
                calibrationForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(calibrationForm.StartCalibration));
            else
                calibrationForm.StartCalibration();
            if (calibrationForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                //get data from calibrationForm
            calibrationForm.Dispose();
        }
        //continue with this threads operation
```

It looks like the call to ShowDialog() however is still throwing an exception,

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CalibrationForm' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on

So I'm currently wondering whether my best option is to try and simply suspend my current thread and wait till the calibration Form finishes to attempt a join, or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Ah, cheers for the answers . I'm guessing I need to abandon the idea of sublcassing Form with it's own Thread...

Comment: Having looked into this some more can someone please confirm if this is in fact a dead end? The new form I'm creating with it's own thread has no interaction (or need anyway) with the primary UI. It exists only to perform a single localised task and return a result to the first thread....

Comment: You have to do all the UI on the main thread. Those are the rules of the game.

Comment: Cheers David, thats the part I'm still struggling with though. My main thread does all it's UI and analyses webcam input using a seperate Thread it manages. In this instance I'd like to suspend this analysing Thread, create/show a new Form that runs it's own Thread (for the duration of it's own existence) and returns a value. Could you possibly post an example of how I could achieve this? (The task this secondary form performs is UI orientated but doesn't require/update any Controls created elsewhere).

Comment: You say "create/show a new Form that runs it's own Thread". No that's not what you do. All UI must run on the UI thread. But we already said that. I would tackle this by signalling to the worker thread that it needs to pause execution. And then get the worker thread to wait on an event that signals that it can resume.

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms, all UI elements must be accessed from the main thread.

You can do background processing on other threads (such as retrieving data from a remote source, or logging) but you cannot create or modify UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, only the main UI thread can interact with UI components.

To interact with the UI from other threads, you have 2 options.  You can either call Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke on a Form/Control or use a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.
[Example of WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2006/02/13/531315.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run all code interacts with your UI on the UI thread. That's a hard rule of WinForms.

If you need to show UI, or interact with existing UI, from your thread, call either Invoke or BeginInvoke depending on whether you want synchronous or asynchronous operation. These methods will execute the UI code on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this to work eventually, my main issue primarily being getting my second form to run it's own task **and** behave like a standard dialog window.

```
public partial class CalibrationForm : Form {

    public CalibrationForm(ISource source) {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.source = source;
        //other setup
    }

    private void Run() {
        while (!finished) {
            //process user input
            this.Invalidate();
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Update));
            else
                Update();
        }
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        finished = true;
    }
```

And then in the calling thread...

```
CalibrationForm calibrationForm = new CalibrationForm(camera);
new Thread(calibrationForm.Run).Start();
if (calibrationForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    //get data from calibrationForm
```

Last thing was to make sure to set the DialogResult properties for the buttons on the form so they would return the appropriate value to the `ShowDialog()` call.

Comment: Why don't you create the background thread within your `CalibrationForm` (inside `OnLoad` or something)? It is rather unusual to do it this way IMO.